# Where can I do my own analysis of exit poll data?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, polling, data-sources, exit-polls

All the media sites do their own rollups of the exit poll data, but the dimensions they pick are static. Is there any site where I can pivot on my own sets of dimensions? E.g. I see married men went overwhelmingly for Trump, but I can't see if that also correlates with age.

Are there any sites that expose a more flexible interface? Or the raw data itself?

Comment: There are lots of organizations that do exit polls, so there isn't really any site that has everything. Also, they don't always share the raw data, or if they do, there may be restrictions (e.g. it's behind a paywall).

Comment: If you can get it at all, it is usually from the website of the firm conducting the poll, which often has cross-tabs. Also, since the data is often collected on a binned basis (are you 18-25, 26-35, . . . ) rather than in open answer form (who old are you), there are some limits to what can be done even with the raw data.

Answer (score 2):

Exit polls conducted by media companies are proprietary data and unlikely to be available to the public.

The best source of electoral opinion data in the United States is the [American National Election Survey](https://electionstudies.org/data-center/) (ANES). They typically do both pre- and post-election surveys with plenty of demographic and other data to play with. You have to register to access the data, but as far as I know there is no real 'vetting' procedure.

Two caveats:

1. The data is not super-easy to work with. They use a stratified sampling strategy, so you will need to weight every observation to derive any estimates.
2. Much of the demographic information will be restricted to researchers with a viable research interest in that data. It's potentially personally identifiable, so it's not available to the public. Look through the data to see if what you want is out there.

And happy hunting!

Answer (score 0):

In the U.S., in 2020, [CNN conducted one set of exit polls](https://www.cnn.com/election/2020/exit-polls/president/national-results), and the [Associated Press Vote Cast exit polls](https://www.npr.org/2020/11/03/929478378/understanding-the-2020-electorate-ap-votecast-survey) was the other main national, comprehensive exit pollster, with publicly available data.

These weren't the only exit polls conducted, and neither of the main polls did as good a job of [polling Jewish voters in 2020](https://www.timesofisrael.com/how-did-us-jews-vote-polls-offer-imperfect-take-though-big-picture-is-clear/) as other exit polls beyond these main two did.